Refresh access token Blazor InteractiveServer render mode?
So I needed to use per page render mode in this Blazor project, most of which are InteractiveServer. In a particular page I would like to swap between InteractiveServer and InteractiveWasm manually, at this time, then it will be InteractiveWasm.
Anyway to get and store data because of this, I use HttpClients.
The issue happens in InteractiveServer mode, if I keep the tab open for more than the access token duration, it expires and following api calls gives 401 NotAuthorized because HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token") still gives the old token.
I tried to trigger the CookieAuthenticationEvents.OnValidatePrincipal with a timer every 5 minutes. I make a javascript fetch call to a dummy api just to trigger this event, given
that the browser appends the cookies  automatically.
So server side a new access token is set along with the other tokens.
I inject the httpContextAccessor at the initialization of the page, and then use it to set the bearer token to the httpClient before every call, using httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token") but even after triggering the refresh on the server, this token is still the old one, the first that was got when page was initialized.
Is there any way to make the HttpClients works without a jwtBearer token and make them send cookies like it happens when you are in InteractiveWasm?

Blazor docs are explicit that you can't really make use of HttpContextAccessor - it can only get you information about the user's first page load on arriving on your site and quite soon after that it may return null.

If security matters at all then the only good option is to ask “how do the docs for this technology say to do it” and then closely follow the docs. The Blazor model is quite different to asp.net razor. What @Yumiao Kong says is good.

What he says shows how to get user data or set tokens in the initial rendering. If i need a new token after sometime the tab has been opened because the initial token has expired, then another solution is needed.

Are you are trying to write one piece of code that will handle Authentication and will be the same code whether running in WebAssembly or running server-side? I take your point that Yumiao referenced the serverside docs, but you are trying to get it working in WebAssembly?

that would be ideal, but i dont mean handling authentication. That i already is figured out. I mean refreshing the access token when expired, that happens after some time the tab has been opened and not refreshed.
WebAssembly rendermode appends cookies when doing httpClients calls, InteractiveServer it seems to me it doesn't, so you need to set the Bearer Token, which expires and i need to refresh it without a full reload of the page

@ScottexBoy have you solved this? I have exactly the same problem and every solution I have come up with, is only some "ugly" workaround

@Marmellad yup, with the javascript call to an api just as you mention. I confirm that it works. Make sure you have your api has the Authorize attribute. I assume in the OnValidatePrincipal event you retrieve new tokens and set the cookies with their values. But also let me try once more to check if the tokens are new, i'm sure my app is working but still.

@ScottexBoy yeah I understand that you refresh the cookie in OnValidatePrincipal, I do the same thing - but how do you tell Blazor and the Blazor circuit to refresh the ClaimsPrincipal from that new cookie? Or how do you read the refreshed values from cookie when you have interactive server mode in Blazor? You simply need to force reload the Blazor to create new circuit and get AuthenticationState with the new values. Is that correct?

@Marmellad well f me, you are right in Blazor the cookie is not refreshed, I don't understand why now the controllers authorize the call even if the cookie is the old one. It failed before. Smh. I'm done with this, i will just increase the token duration for this particular app.

Interactively-rendered server-side Blazor operates over a SignalR connection with the client. Authentication is managed via the SignalR hub and entirely within the circuit.
refer to the tutorial: Server-side Blazor authentication

IHttpContextAccessor must be avoided with interactive rendering
because there isn't a valid HttpContext available.
IHttpContextAccessor can be used for components that are statically
rendered on the server. However, we recommend avoiding it if possible.

So, you could not get the new token with the code HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")
Below are two ways may help you solve the issue.
1 Using the built-in AuthenticationStateProvider service:

The built-in AuthenticationStateProvider service obtains
authentication state data from ASP.NET Core's HttpContext.User.

private async Task GetClaimsPrincipalData()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider
            .GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity is not null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            authMessage = $"{user.Identity.Name} is authenticated.";
            claims = user.Claims;
            surname = user.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname)?.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            authMessage = "The user is NOT authenticated.";
        }
    }

2 Passing tokens to a server-side Blazor app:

Tokens available outside of the Razor components in a server-side
Blazor app can be passed to components with the approach described in
this section.

For detailed steps you can refer to this tutorial: Pass tokens to a server-side Blazor app

Im sorry but the solutions you have provided are about user informations, which i know i should use authenticationState task and the other is about setting tokens on initialization. Not if the tab has been opened for sometime and the access token expired. Should i register difference services for client and server and not use httpclients for server rendering?

Could you kindly provide a sample demo that can reproduce the issue?
